# Runtime configuration of SSL/TLS http client on Android with client authentication

Tags: android, authentication, bouncycastle, ssl

The following test setup runs fine on the Android emulator. It opens a SSL/TLS based connection to an
external server using mutual authentication:

ca.crt (to verify the server certificate):
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
BASE64 ENCODED STUFF
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

client.p12 (including a client certificate signed by a private CA which is trusted by the server): PKCS#12 format

The Java/Android code which runs succesfull:

```
trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("bks");
trustStore.load(null, null);
caCertificate = getX509Certificate("/some/path/ca.crt");
trustStore.setCertificateEntry("ca-cert", caCertificate);

keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
keyStore.load(null, null);
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/some/path/client.p12");
keyStore.load(is, "passwd".toCharArray());

TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, null);

context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

URL url = new URL("https://www.backend.com");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
BufferedReader urlReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
while ( (inputLine=urlReader.readLine()) != null ){
    System.out.println(inputLine);
}
```

However, client.p12 is not available at runtime. The http client receives following configuration via a separate 
dedicated channel:

- PEM encoded X509 client certificate (client.crt)
- DER formatted private key client (client.der)

Therefore I changed the keystore intitialisation above taking the client.p12 as input, into following:

```
keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("bks");
keyStore.load(null, null);
clientCertificate = getX509Certificate("/some/path/client.crt");
byte[] privateKey =  getBytesFromFile("/some/path/client.der");
Certificate[] chain = new Certificate[2];
chain[1] = caCertificate;
chain[0] = clientCertificate;        
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("client-cert", clientCertificate);
keyStore.setKeyEntry("client-cert-key", privateKey, chain);
```

runtime an exception is thrown when executing

```
context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
---->  context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

java.lang.RuntimeException: forget something!
at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyStore$StoreEntry.getObject(JDKKeyStore.java:314)
at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyStore.engineGetKey(JDKKeyStore.java:604)
at java.security.KeyStoreSpi.engineGetEntry(KeyStoreSpi.java:376)
at java.security.KeyStore.getEntry(KeyStore.java:734)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerImpl.<init>(KeyManagerImpl.java:72)
```

Summary: everything is working using a pcks12 certificate/privatekey pair, but not using the two in the mentioned format.

Any suggestions what is going wrong or a suggestion for implementing client authentication given the client.der/client.pem mentioned previously?

P.S. running the keytool runtime is not an option, because I don't have it at runtime and I do not want to go that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple: passing a key as byte array is not implemented. Quote from `JDKKeyStore.java`:

```
        else
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("forget something!");
            // TODO
            // if we get to here key was saved as byte data, which
            // according to the docs means it must be a private key
            // in EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo (PKCS8 format), later...
            //
        }
```

You can try to register your key and certificate using the `void setKeyEntry(String alias, Key key, char[] password, Certificate[] chain)` method, it seems it is supported (untested).

Answer (score 0):

for me it worked after changing

```
sslContext.init(kmf.keyManagers, null, null)
```

into

```
sslContext.init(kmf.keyManagers, null, SecureRandom())
```